# TableView into tabBarController

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

i started a tabbed application project, and on my first view i want to get a populated list so i declared  a NSArray like follow:

```
@interface agrospineFirstViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate     ,UITableViewDataSource>
{
NSArray  *JournalList;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSArray *JournalList;
@end
```

and i added the following on the .m :

[super viewDidLoad];

```
//initialisation de la liste
JournalList = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"journal1",@"journal2",nil];


//initialisation du table View 
UITableView* tableView=[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]style:UITableViewStylePlain];


//population de la vue


-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [JournalList count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

// Configuration de la cellule

NSString *cellValue = [JournalList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;
return cell;

}
```

i also droped the tablelist into the view... but still showing an error on numberOfRowsInSection asking to replace ":" by ";" 
any help advice to improve ?

Thank you for your time

Comment: U need to alloc your array, 
JournalList = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects: @"journal1",@"journal2",nil];

Comment: You should paste all code of the view controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have not closed **viewDidLoad** method like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  //initialisation de la liste
  JournalList = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"journal1",@"journal2",nil];


  //initialisation du table View 
  UITableView* tableView=[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]style:UITableViewStylePlain];


  //population de la vue
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [JournalList count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

  if (cell == nil)

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

  // Configuration de la cellule

  NSString *cellValue = [JournalList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;
  return cell;

}
```

Comment: it is closed i didn't copy it

Comment: @SreeCharan array is initialized with this code: `JournalList = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"journal1",@"journal2",nil];` but it should be retained.

Comment: @SreeCharan it is automatically allocated when called like i did

Comment: @SreeCharan yes the error is gone but i am still not getting results... i am wondering if i did right initializing the tableview using [[UIScreen mainScreen]applicationFrame] for the frame as i am using a bartab below

Comment: Are you using table view in xib file?

Answer (score 2):

You dont need this
 `UITableView* tableView=[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]style:UITableViewStylePlain];`

Just add table to the viewController and add that viewController name on appDelegate class like this

```
UIViewController *homeViewController = [[[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:homeViewController,nil];
```

Just give delagate and datasource connections in xib class

Comment: i am going to ask a question about that i'll send you a link to it

Comment: i tried to understand what you wrote here but i don't think i get it.. what you're trying to say is that i should add an array of view controllers into the tabBarController?